# stop dynamically created Audio

Tags: javascript, audio, dynamic, element

I create dynamically on click event (play) audio element like this

```
var myAudio = document.createElement('audio');
myAudio.setAttribute('src', mp3link);
```

than I let it play

```
myAudio.play()
```

Now the problem comes when I click on another element and the next track starts to play, I would like to stop before all running audios in this case. How do I do that?

Comment: use `myAudio.pause();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Collect all audio elements with `querySelectorAll('audio')` in a NodeList.
2. Iterate through the NodeList with a `for` loop.
3. On each iteration (loop), `.pause()` then reset the `currentTime = 0`. There's no `stop()` method, so you must pause then reset the time to 0.

   - In the Snippet, start the 2 players then the <kbd>Play</kbd> button.
   - Click the <kbd>stopAll</kbd> button.
   - Click the <kbd>Play</kbd> button again.

Basically, stop all players, then play the exact one you want. That's how it's done normally. Of course you'll have the dynamic players instead of the hard coded type, but the `stopAll()` function will work with the dynamically created audio as well.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var xAudio = document.createElement('audio');
var mp3Link = 'http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/pf-righteous.mp3'
xAudio.setAttribute('src', mp3Link);
document.body.appendChild(xAudio);

function play() {
  xAudio.play();
}

function stopAll() {
  var xGroup = document.querySelectorAll('audio');

  for (var i = 0; i < xGroup.length; i++) {
    xGroup[i].pause();
    xGroup[i].currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <audio src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/00.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/balls.mp3" controls></audio>
  <br/>


  <button onclick="stopAll()">StopAll</button>
  <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call play directly. Make an object that has a property currentAudio. Give it a function play that takes an audio object as a parameter. When you hit play and pass it a new audio element, you can stop the old one before playing the new one, and save the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Create only one `<audio id="audio"></audio>` in the html

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('audio');
myAudio.setAttribute('src', mp3link);
myAudio.play()
```

Every time you clicked new track, it will replace the mp3 source link.