# How to stop an audio element created by a function? IE: audio = new Audio()

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm creating a Canvas game and I'm using this to stop all audios:

```
  document.querySelectorAll("audio").forEach((el) => {
  if (
    el.id === "song1" ||
    el.id === "song2" ||
    el.id === "song3"
  ) {
    el.volume = 0;
    el.pause();
  } else {
    el.currentTime = 0;
    el.volume = 0;
    el.pause();
  }
});
```

The problem I have is that this stop all the audios within the `<head></head>` tag in the html file (preloaded ones), but it does not work for audios created dinamically

```
function soundGo(newAudio, boolean) {
  if (boolean === true) {
    let audio = new Audio(newAudio);
    audio.volume = 0.1;
    audio.play();
} else {
    let audio = new Audio(newAudio);
    audio.volume = 0;
    audio.pause();
}
}
```

I want to know if it's possible to iterate all the elements created with new Audio(). The querySelectorAll does not the trick, at least in my case (maybe I'm doing it wrong...).

I tried this also:
[stop dynamically created Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394307/stop-dynamically-created-audio)

Comment: The Audios created are not inserted into the DOM. So you can't find them with `document.querySelectorAll`. You would need to save all audios in an array `audios.push(audio);` and then iterate over the array to pause them `audios.forEach(audio => audio.pause())`.

Comment: Damn, I didn't thought about this ... haha. I'll try it, thx!. I was expecting to be possible to iterate to objects created dinamically. Thx thx!!